# מַה נִּשְּׁתַּנָה הַלַּיְלָה הַזֶּה מִכָּל הַלֵּילוֹת - What is the etymology of נִּשְּׁתַּנָה (nishtana)?

Tags: hebrew, grammar-dikduk, passover-seder-hagada

I can find לְהִשְׁתַּנּוֹת where נִשְׁתַּנֶּה (nishtane) would translate to "we will change (ourselves)", but i cannot find where נִּשְּׁתַּנָה (nishtana) derives from. Or is it just old biblical grammar with no relation to spoken Hebrew?

Comment: I don't think this question is correct for this site as it is not about Judaism. Also not clear what you are asking, etymology or grammar?